# ionic2 AlertController scope issues

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using ionic2/angular2 application for developing mobile application. we have to call another external API to show one dialog box. After returning from another control to my application the **AlertController** scope is not working.

```
    import {AlertController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
    export class BalanceInquiryPage {
      constructor(){
        public alertCtrl: AlertController,
        public events: Events,
      }

      public balanceDetials(formdata): void {
          //fetch the device details from sqlite storage
          this.databaseService.getDeviceDetails().then((result) => {
             this.commonServices.getGeoLocation(this.deviceObj);
             setTimeout(() => {
               let geodevice = this.shareService.getDeviceDetails();
               let balanceenq = JSON.stringify({"mobileNumber":"9199403562", "expDate":"","cardDigits":""});         
              if (window.npciLib){
                 window.npciLib.balanceenq(balanceenq, function (data) {                  
                      let dataobj = JSON.parse(data);
                      if(dataobj.resp.result == 'SUCCESS'){
                        //this.events.publish('alert:presented', 'Success', 'Balance Enquiry Success.', MyaccountPage);
                        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                          title: "Success",
                          subTitle: "balance",
                          buttons: [
                            {
                              text: 'Ok',
                              handler: () => {

                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        });
                        alert.present();
                      }
                      else{
                        //this.events.publish('alert:presented', 'Fail', 'There was an error in balance enquiry.', 'samePage');
                      }
                   }, function (error) {
                      console.log('error block-'+error);
                   });
               }
              }, 1000);
         }, (error) => {
           console.log('Error', error.err);
         });
        }
   }
```

I am getting the following error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alertCtrl' of null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use arrow function here

```
window.npciLib.balanceenq(balanceenq, function (data) {
```

like

```
window.npciLib.balanceenq(balanceenq, (data) => {
```

This way `this` will be referenced to your component instance

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function in Angular 2; it will solve scope issue.

```
   import {AlertController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
   export class BalanceInquiryPage {
      constructor(){
       public alertCtrl: AlertController,
       public events: Events,
     }

      public balanceDetials(formdata): void {
          //fetch the device details from sqlite storage
           this.databaseService.getDeviceDetails().then((result) => {
           this.commonServices.getGeoLocation(this.deviceObj);
           setTimeout(() => {
           let geodevice = this.shareService.getDeviceDetails();
           let balanceenq = JSON.stringify({"mobileNumber":"9199403562", 
"expDate":"","cardDigits":""});         
          if (window.npciLib){
             window.npciLib.balanceenq(balanceenq ,(data) =>  {                  
                  let dataobj = JSON.parse(data);
                  if(dataobj.resp.result == 'SUCCESS'){
                    //this.events.publish('alert:presented', 'Success', 
    'Balance Enquiry Success.', MyaccountPage);
                    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                      title: "Success",
                      subTitle: "balance",
                      buttons: [
                        {
                          text: 'Ok',
                          handler: () => {

                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    });
                    alert.present();
                  }
                  else{
                    //this.events.publish('alert:presented', 'Fail', 'There 
    was an error in balance enquiry.', 'samePage');
                  }
               }, function (error) {
                  console.log('error block-'+error);
               });
           }
          }, 1000);
     }, (error) => {
       console.log('Error', error.err);
     });
     }
 }
```